# How to set a Radio Button Group's width to fill the width of the parent container in Bootstrap?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, bootstrap-5

Is there a way to set Radio Button Groups that span the width of the parent container / dbc.column? I am currently using Dash Plotly and Python to create a web app and the Radio Button Groups I've created in a column of width 2 do not span the width of the column despite numerous attempts. Here's how I am defining the Radio Button Group using the [tutorial found at the bottom of the page here.](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/button_group/)

```
html.Div([
      dbc.RadioItems(
          id="pr-select",
          className="btn-group d-flex",
          labelClassName="btn btn-info",
          labelCheckedClassName="active",
          style={'width': '100%'},
          options=[{'label': 'Opt1', 'value': 'True', 'disabled': 'True'},
                   {'label': 'Opt2', 'value': 'False', 'disabled': 'True'},
                   ],
          ),
      ],
      className='radio-group mb-2',
      style={'width': '100%'}
 ),
```

As you can see, I've already tried setting the width to 100% in the style, however that has had no effect to the width at all. For reference, this is what it outputs on the app. As you can see, all the radio groups span different widths relative to the column they are in. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

**EDIT:**
I've included sample code below if you would like to reproduce this and play with the CSS. Please also note that the file must be called app.py and must live in a directory with a folder called assets with a mystyle.css file using the [custom css listed at the bottom of the page here](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/button_group/):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY],
                suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
                meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                            'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}],
                )

app.layout = dbc.Container([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.Div([
                            dbc.RadioItems(
                                id="hand-select",
                                className="btn-group",
                                labelClassName="btn btn-info",
                                labelCheckedClassName="active",
                                options=[
                                    {'label': 'Opt1', 'value': 'Left', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                    {'label': 'Opt2', 'value': 'Both', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                    {'label': 'Opt3', 'value': 'Right', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                ],
                                style={"margin-top": "auto",
                                       }
                            ),
                        ],
                            className='radio-group mb-2',
                            style={'width': '100%'}
                            #style={'max-width': 'fit-content'}
                        ),
                        html.Div([
                            dbc.RadioItems(
                                id="pr-select",
                                className="btn-group d-flex",
                                labelClassName="btn btn-info",
                                labelCheckedClassName="active",
                                #inputClassName='mw-100',
                                style={'width': '100%'},
                                options=[
                                    {'label': 'Opt1', 'value': 'True', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                    {'label': 'Opt2', 'value': 'False', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                ],
                            ),
                        ],
                            className='radio-group mb-2',
                            style={'width': '100%'}
                        ),
                        html.Div([
                            dbc.RadioItems(
                                id="cs-select",
                                className="btn-group",
                                labelClassName="btn btn-info",
                                labelCheckedClassName="active",
                                options=[
                                    {'label': 'Option One.........', 'value': 'True', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                    {'label': 'Option Two.........', 'value': 'False', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                ],
                            ),
                        ],
                            className='radio-group mb-2'
                        ),
                    ], width=3, style={'margin-right': '0px',
                                       'margin-left': '0px',
                                       'backgroundColor': 'black'},),

                    dbc.Col([
                ], width=3),

                dbc.Col([

                ], width=6)
            ])
]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: maybe first open `DevTools` in browser to see HTML for this page and then you can set different CSS values to test which value may change layout.

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could simply copy and run it - to see it in `DevTools` and test some `CSS`

Comment: You may try the `w-100` class

Comment: @KhushalJangid I've tried the w-100 class and it doesn't affect the radio button group at all unfortunately. I've also tried style={'width': '100%'} but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @furas I've included the minimal working code as an edit to the post and I will try to mess with the DevTools when I get the chance!

Answer (score 2):

`RadioItems` generates `HTML` like this

```html
<div id="pr-select">

  <div class="form-check">
     <input type="radio" ...>
     <label ... >Opt1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
     <input type="radio" ...>
     <label ... >Opt2</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

And it needs `'width':'100%'` in three places:

1. in external `<div id="pr-select">` and this can be added using `style={'width':'100%'}`
2. in `<label ... >` and this can be added using `styleLabel={'width':'100%'}`
3. in `<div class="form-check">` and this has no method in code.
   The only solution which I found is to create file `assets/style.css` which `dash` will load automatically
   (documentation: [Adding CSS & JS and Overriding the Page-Load Template](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources))

   ```
   .form-check {
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```

---

**assets/style.css**

```
.form-check {
   width: 100%;
}
```

**main.py**

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY],
                suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
                meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                            'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}],
               )

app.layout = dbc.Container([
                dbc.Row([

                    dbc.Col([
                        
                        html.Div([
                            dbc.RadioItems(
                                id="hand-select",
                                className="btn-group",
                                labelClassName="btn btn-info",
                                labelCheckedClassName="active",
                                inputClassName="btn-check",
                                options=[
                                    {'label': 'Opt1', 'value': 'Left',  'disabled': 'True'},
                                    {'label': 'Opt2', 'value': 'Both',  'disabled': 'True'},
                                    {'label': 'Opt3', 'value': 'Right', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                ],
                                style={'width': '100%'},       # <---  for external <div>
                                labelStyle={'width': '100%'},  # <---  for <input>
                            )
                            ],
                            className="radio-group",
                            style={"margin-top": "5px", "margin-bottom": "5px"}
                        ),
                        
                        html.Div([
                            dbc.RadioItems(
                                id="pr-select",
                                className="btn-group",
                                labelClassName="btn btn-info",
                                labelCheckedClassName="active",
                                inputClassName="btn-check",
                                options=[
                                    {'label': 'Opt1', 'value': 'True',  'disabled': 'True'},
                                    {'label': 'Opt2', 'value': 'False', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                ],
                                style={'width': '100%'},      # <---  for external <div>
                                labelStyle={'width':'100%'},  # <---  for <input>
                            )
                            ],
                            className="radio-group",
                            style={"margin-top": "5px", "margin-bottom": "5px"}
                        ),
                        
                        html.Div([
                            dbc.RadioItems(
                                id="cs-select",
                                className="btn-group",
                                labelClassName="btn btn-info",
                                labelCheckedClassName="active",
                                inputClassName="btn-check",
                                options=[
                                    {'label': 'Option One.........', 'value': 'True',  'disabled': 'True'},
                                    {'label': 'Option Two.........', 'value': 'False', 'disabled': 'True'},
                                ],
                                style={'width':'100%'},       # <---  for external <div>
                                labelStyle={'width':'100%'},  # <---  for <input>
                            )
                            ],
                            className="radio-group",
                            style={"margin-top": "5px", "margin-bottom": "5px"}
                        ),
                    ],
                    width=3, style={'margin-right': '0px',
                                    'margin-left': '0px',
                                    'backgroundColor': 'black'},
                    ),

            ])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug=True
    app.run_server()
```

[image]